# Access IIF statement not returning correct amount

Tags: ms-access, iif

My work involves reviewing the invoice for the shipment of packages. In some cases, the package was re-weighed in transit and weighed more than we had registered it to be. We get billed with the new weight.

I need my IIF statement to return the Adjusted Weight if there is one and the Delivery weight if there is none in the Microsoft Access database.

IIf([Adjustments]![AdjWeight] Is Null, [Deliveries]![DelWeight],[Adjustments]![AdjWeight])

Cell Specifications (not sure if these are important)
Delivery Weight:Number, Single, Fixed, 2 decimal places 
Adjusted Weight:Number, Single, Fixed, 2 decimal places

The statement does return a result but NOT the right amount.

Here are a two examples of the results:

```
Delivery  Adjusted   Result
========  ========   ===========
  0.97      Null     0.67000017 
  0.63      1.06     1.059999943
  1.00      Null     1.00    
  0.63      1.00     1.00
```

However if the weight of either the delivery or Adjustment is 1, it returns a value of 1.

Comment: `IIf(IsNull([Adjustments]![AdjWeight], [Deliveries]![DelWeight],[Adjustments]![AdjWeight])`   ...note you seem to have missed some square brackets.

Comment: The problem seems to relate to "However if the weight of either...is 1..." Please be more precise. Can you illustrate with a few examples of errant results?

Comment: I hope I did not take too great a liberty, but I filled in some errant results on my own. You should be able to edit them easily if I am not understanding.

Comment: It would be a good idea to include sample data from both tables. Some of your differences seem to be due to floating point problems ( http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/864827-single-data-type-dangerous ).

Comment: Smandoli, thank you for pointing out the missing ] in my iif statement. I have fixed that. 
I think Fionnuala hit it on the nose. I spoke with a friend over the phone and he suggested converting the kg to grams to make them whole numbers. I know nothing about floating point numbers but have added it to my reading list. Can't wait to try the solution tomorrow at work. Thank you both.

Comment: You could also use nz([Adjustments].[AdjWeight],[Deliveries].[DelWeight]) which means if the first condition is null then return the second.

Comment: The currency data type is the most accurate for decimals in MS Access.